# Why does "IQueryable.Where()" provide different results than "IEnumerable.Where()" in this query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use linq to filter some rows from an EF Core dataset and I don't understand why filtering an IEnumerable vs filtering an IQueryable are giving me different results.

```
        var query = _db.Jobs
            .IsDelivered()
            .Include(a => a.JobExtras)
            .Include(a => a.Tips)
            .Include(a => a.Payments)
            .HasPayments();

        var query1 = query
            .ToList()
            .Where(a => a.Payments.Sum(b => b.Amount)
                         - a.Price.Value
                         - a.Discount
                         - a.JobExtras.Sum(c => c.Price)
                         - a.Tips.Sum(d => d.Amount)
                         > 0);

        var query2 = query
           .Where(a => a.Payments.Sum(b => b.Amount)
                         - a.Price.Value
                         - a.Discount
                         - a.JobExtras.Sum(c => c.Price)
                         - a.Tips.Sum(d => d.Amount)
                         > 0);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Record Count[Before Where Clause]: {query.Count()}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Record Count[ToList() version]: {query1.Count()}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Record Count[w/out ToList()]: {query2.Count()}");
```

Here is the output:

```
Record Count[Before Where Clause]: 8379
Record Count[ToList() version]: 5921
Record Count[w/out ToList()]: 0
```

Why is the IEnumerable version producing 5921 records and the IQueryable version producing 0 records?

Comment: Are there `NULL`s in any of those columns in your calculation? Any math or logic on `NULL` will yield `NULL`, including `NULL > 0` -> `NULL` which is not true so it's functionally equivalent to false.

Comment: I thought perhaps that was the case too so I removed the only term that is nullable "Price" but same result.  Plus, if that were the case, shouldn't that affect query1 just like query2 ?

Comment: No. When you call `ToList`, that executes the query, at which point you're operating on .NET types/values. `Sum` will ignore `null` instead of yielding `null`, and `Count` will count a `null` item instead of ignoring it. That would be moot if your source data doesn't have `NULL`s, but I think you may be getting `NULL` when you have no items to aggregate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first query executes in memory using .NET types, and `Enumerable.Sum()`. Any nulls passed into `Sum` are skipped, so some of your data is passing the `> 0` test.

The second query executes in the database and uses SQL's `SUM`. If any part of the expression in your `Where` clause contains a null, that expression will evaluate as null. Taking that expression and comparing it (`null > 0`) always evaluates as false in the SQL, so all your rows are filtered.

Your second query might be fixable. I have no proof of this as I don't know your model (i.e. what's nullable or not), and am not sure if EF can translate this:

```
.Where(a => a.Payments.Where(x => x != null).Sum(b => b.Amount)
     - a.Price.Value
     - a.Discount
     - a.JobExtras.Where(x => x != null).Sum(c => c.Price)
     - a.Tips.Where(x => x != null).Sum(d => d.Amount)
     > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for this train of thought.  madreflection correctly mentioned NULL as the problem, but not the right area. I think the problem isn't a nullable field, its a nullable set.  Iqueryable is SQL, and SQL deals with 'sets', not objects.  So when you try to do a Tips.Sum(blah blah), if there are no Tips rows (Which there are several Job objects that have no "children" tip rows), SQL returns 'NULL' where as .NET returns a '0' making this whole query unusable via SQL.  Thoughts?

Comment: If I am correct in my last comment, that means your attempted 'fix' won't work either because Tips.Where(x => x!= null)  will still result in a NULL if there are 0 tips rows in the DB.

Comment: I marked this the correct answer because it sent me down the path to finding the solution.  I created an answer below with the final working solution.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @FrankBusalacchi: FWIW, I alluded to sets in the second comment when I said *"no items to aggregate"*.

Comment: @madreflection -- Yes,  I agree you alluded to it as well, and you were the first to respond too!  That is why I said in my answer that based on info provided by the both of you..  Its also why I upvoted your comment.  I appreciate your help and effort on my question!  Thank you and thank everyone else that took the time to read it and offer thoughts, suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, had a couple things to try, but I read that you found that the issue was the missing children.

I had a quick test and the following should work in your case:

```
  var query2 = query
       .Where(a => a.Payments.Sum(b => b.Amount)
                     - a.Price.Value
                     - a.Discount
                     - (a.JobExtras.Any() ? a.JobExtras.Sum(c => c.Price) : 0)
                     - (a.Tips.Any() ? a.Tips.Sum(d => d.Amount) : 0)
                     > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

So based on the information provided by Kit and madreflection:

I just reseeded the DB and ensured that there ARE rows in the 3 child tables: Payments, JobExtras and Tips.

Voila, the query works with both IQueryable version as well as IEnumerable version.  I get the same number of rows.

So, to summarize, **the answer to the question is that the problem with the IQueryable query is that if there are no children rows in the DB for the objects that I am trying to SUM, SQL returns NULL instead of 0**

Thank you for the help!

That behavior is an interesting GOTCHA.

So now, is there a way to fix the IQueryable query to contend with the possibility that the children objects (Tips, Payments, JobExtras) could be 'empty sets' (No rows) ?

=============
***Working solution (credit to @Steve Py & @madreflection)***

```
var query2 = query
   .Where(a => (a.Payments.Any() ? a.Payments.Sum(b => b.Amount) : 0M)
               - (a.Price ?? 0M)
               - a.Discount
               - (a.JobExtras.Any() ? a.JobExtras.Sum(c => c.Price) : 0M)
               - (a.Tips.Any() ? a.Tips.Sum(d => d.Amount) : 0M)
               > 0M);

// Even better solution [cleaner SQL generated] provided by: @madreflection

   .Where(a => (a.Payments.Sum(b => (decimal?)b.Amount) ?? 0M)
               - (a.Price ?? 0M)
               - a.Discount
               - (a.JobExtras.Sum(c => (decimal?)c.Price) ?? 0M)
               - (a.Tips.Sum(d => (decimal?)d.Amount) ?? 0M)
               > 0M);
```

Comment: Could you do `a.Payments.Sum(b => (decimal?)b.Amount) ?? 0M)` instead?

Comment: As Kit alluded to, it comes down to the behavior of IQueryable.Sum() when it is presented with an empty collection.  IQueryable.Sum() = NULL when the collection is empty.  IEnumerable.Sum() = 0 when the collection is empty.  SQL purist would probably argue that it is correct, but in my opinion, IQueryable.Sum() and IEnumerable.Sum should have consistent behavior and either both return Null, or both return 0.

Comment: I get it; that all makes sense. I'm just trying to simplify your expression. The result of `Sum` isn't always `0`. For a nullable value type, it's `null`, which you can coalesce to `0`. Casting `b.Amount` (for example) to nullable would eliminate the need for the call to `Any` and thus the ternary operator. Theoretically -- you'd have to test it to confirm -- it would be able to generate better SQL.

Comment: @madreflection: I just swapped in your suggestion and it did work as well.  I definitely prefer the way that looks over the ternary, and although I haven't investigated yet, I would agree with you that the generated SQL is better with your approach. I will update my answer and provide that alternative as well in case someone else reads this in the future.   Thank you for your continued efforts.

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Comment: I think semantically it makes even more sense to rewrite your suggestion as: ((decimal?)a.Tips.Sum(d => d.Amount) ?? 0M)

Comment: Now you're back to where you were before. You're casting a non-nullable value type to nullable and then coalescing it to 0, but you'll never get a null to coalesce. You're actually doing `((decimal?)(non-working-way)) ?? 0M`, where "non-working-way" is exactly the expression that didn't work before.

Comment: It actually works.  The original problem was because a.Tips.Sum(d=> d.Amount) evaluated to NULL when there were no Tips rows.  That null caused the entire math clause of  Payments - Price - Discount - JobExtras -Tips to evaluate to NULL making the Where clause reduce to NULL > 0M which was always false resulting in a 0 row set.  With my adaption of your solution, if a.Tips.Sum() returns null, it obviously remains NULL but of type Decimal? which gets coallesced to 0M, and letting the math statement work.

Comment: Will there ever be no payments? Or no job extras? If either of those can be empty those expressions will be similarly affected. Semantically, casting within the `Sum` expression is actually correct because it does to the data type of the column in the aggregate what SQL does in the same context (I'm stretching for effect). And again, the other way is a no-op.

Comment: Yes, I guarded those as well.  To your implied point, anyone attempting to Sum a child collection that can't guarantee there will be children needs to "guard" the Sum statement.  As I mentioned earlier, it seems like EFcore team should make IQueryable.Sum consistent with IEnumerable.Sum and return 0 instead of Null.  IMHO  logically speaking, "Summing" something should result in a number in my opinion.

Comment: `IEnumerable` behaves in a way that does not comply with ANSI SQL. They could do `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;` before the query but that would have other consequences. I don't see them doing that. Also, there's a lot of information about this out there and has been since the earliest versions; it's not exactly an edge case. Really, the hardest part of this was understanding your data without ever seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Jobs.Price as the only nullable value in the query then Iqueryable linq query could be rewritten as follow:

```
.Where(a => a.Payments.Sum(b => b.Amount)
     - a.Price.Value
     - a.Discount
     - a.JobExtras.Sum(c => c.Price ?? 0)
     - a.Tips.Sum(d => d.Amount)
     > 0);
```

Comment: The only nullable field in any of the objects is Jobs.Price.  Trying to do b => Amount ?? 0 won't even compile because Amount is not nullable.  Somehow when there are not Payment/Tips/JobExtras rows in the DB, the expression a.JobExtras.Sum(c=>c.Price) has to evaluate to 0 instead of NULL